# Buying used computer - any identifying hardare specs sent when surfing web?

Tags: security, privacy, tracking

this is one of those "Things I should know and was afraid to ask" questions.

I'm considering buying a used laptop for the first time - and I had a thought - even if I wipe the hard drive and re-install an OS (probably a Linux distro) from scratch, does any indentifying information about the hardware get sent to servers when visiting web sites?  Probably not your average website - but those pesky ad trackers are getting pretty sophisticated at finding identifiable bits.  As in, if the previous owner had been up to questionable activities, do I now look to sophisticated trackers like I'm the same laptop just with a new OS and IP?

I'm 90% certain not.  Just checking to be sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Websites don't have as much information about your device as software installed on the computer will have, but they do have a good bit of information. https://ipleak.net shows some information about your computer, but nifty trackers can surely gather more. "NoScript" for Firefox or "ScriptSafe" for Chrome are two add-ons which are very good at giving trackers a hard time. As for those hardware trails left, I don't think you have to worry about much. Those who would care about your PC's activities enough for you to have worries will likely know about it having a new owner anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer most probably belongs to a model of which there exist many such in the
world. So your hardware, not being unique, is not a good enough identification.
But it does take part in your defined fingerprint.

To achieve a better fingerprint, marketeers will add many other factors,
such as your browser, your installed add-ons/extensions, or any other detail they
can get about your operating system and browser.

As this is not enough, they will also try to sneak some sort of cookie into
your browser that will identify you uniquely.

As you are going to change ISP, IP address, router, operating system,
browser, add-ons/extensions and perhaps more,
I don't think that you run any risk.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of a mobo serial #, or an hdd serial #, that would uniquely ID a machine.  Or if there was a PC equivalent of an IMEI #.  Outside of that, the only hardware info I know that gets sent to a website by a browser is screen resolution - and even then, I think it's only what it's set to in the OS, not the physical native resolution of the hardware.  So, if you guys are comfirming that no, there is no machine or component identifiers sent, then that would confirm there's no issue.

Comment: No, JavaScript cannot access this. This is only exposed if you use Java or IE with ActiveX. Don't worry: My own ISP recycles IP address, so it happens rarely that websites refuse my connection because of illegal activities on one day but all is ok the next day. I never had legal problems, and you won't either.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  I make note that, apparently you say, these kinds of identifyiers can be exposed by Java or IE with ActiveX.  This is important.  So - never enable Java, never use IE with ActiveX.